# Seelah Powers to help

Tags: pathfinder-adventures

In the mobile game Pathfinder Adventures a ! next to the character represents they can help in some way.  For example, contributing a blessing for an extra dice during a check.  Below are two screen shots:

The first is toward the end of someone's turn.  The icon indicates that Seelah can help somehow.  Is this correct and if so how?

[image: End of Turn]

The second is in the middle of combat and you can see from the picture that Seelah has no blessing cards to help out.  So how can Seelah help in this battle when she is in a different location?  Note: It is Kyra who is in battle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first screenshot, it's hard to know without looking at Seelah's hand.  She might be holding, for example, a healing potion or a buff spell.

For the second screenshot, I think she has the exclamation mark because she can use the Temple's ability: "...any character at another location can evade an encounter and move here..."  My group always played this ability as being always-on, but perhaps the PACG engine interprets the ability as being an activated ability of the character at the location.

Comment: Actually the hand you see in the second shot was her hand, as I was able to take the screen shots back to back.  The second one makes sense but in the digital game how is that ability activated.